# Theta vacua eigenstates

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, classical-field-theory, instantons

I have been trying to prove the very simple result that the eigenstates of an operator with matrix elements

$$
\langle n^\prime | H | n \rangle \sim g(|n^\prime-n|),
$$
in a basis $\{|n\rangle\}^{+\infty}_{n=-\infty}$, have eigenstates of the form

$$
|\theta\rangle = \sum_n e^{-in\theta}|n \rangle,
$$
to no success.

I have attempted the obvious, i.e., assuming $|\theta\rangle = \sum_n f_n(\theta)|n \rangle$ is an eigenstate, together with the first condition on $H$, and trying to find a requirement on the $f_n$.

It seems the obstacle is that the original basis is countably infinite (while the latter is continuous, at that), and I have no idea how to reach the stated conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
H |\theta\rangle = H \sum_n e^{in\theta}|n\rangle\\
=\sum_{n,n'}e^{in\theta} |n'\rangle\langle n'|H|n\rangle\\
=\sum_{n,n'} e^{in\theta}|n'\rangle g(n'-n)\\
= \sum_{n,n'} e^{i(n-n')\theta} g(n-n') e^{in'\theta}|n'\rangle\\
$$
Change summation indices to $n'$ and $m= n-n'$ to get
$$
\left(\sum_m g(m)e^{im\theta}\right) \sum_{n' } e^{in'\theta}|n'\rangle\\
=\lambda|\theta\rangle
$$
where $\lambda= \sum_m g(m)e^{im\theta}$. The eigenvalue  will be real if $g(n)$ is real and $g(n)=g(-n)$. More generally $\lambda$  is real if $g(-n)= [g(n)]^*$.

There no problem with one index set, the $n$, being discrete and the other, $\theta$, being continuous. This happens all the time with Hibert-space bases.

Note that we have orthogonality
$$
\langle\theta|\theta'\rangle = \sum_{nn'}\langle n|n'\rangle e^{i\theta' n'}e^{-i\theta n}\\
=\sum_n e^{in(\theta'-\theta)}\\
= 2\pi \sum_m \delta(\theta'-\theta+2\pi m),
$$
so we can restrict $\theta$ to the range $[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Hi mike. I think you can tell OP that their eigenvalue is real, since as OP specified $g(n) = g(|n|) = g(-n)$.

Comment: @hft  He needs $g$ real as well.

Comment: I'm guessing that maybe OP meant to imply that $H$ is Hermitian (by denoting it with the letter "H")... but, yes, he does not say this in his post, so you are right.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you! I had actually no problem in verifying that such $|\theta \rangle$ does the job -- what I wanted was to show the other way around, i.e., that an eigenstate of such an operator (which is indeed to be the selfadjoint hamiltonian) **has** to be of this form.

Comment: You can use the fact that the unitary operator $T$ that maps  $T|n\rangle = |n+1\rangle$ commutes with $H$, and $T|\theta\rangle = e^{-i\theta} |\theta\rangle$ to get somewhere.  However it might be possible to find a $g(n)$ such that $\lambda(\theta) = \lambda(\theta')$ for different $\theta$, $ \theta'$. Then $\alpha|\theta\rangle + \beta   | \theta'\rangle$ would be an eigenvector, but not of the single $\theta$ form.

Comment: Why is it possible to say that $<n'| H |n> \equiv g(n'-n)$? Why couldn't this be a function of both $n$ and $n'$, instead of a function of their difference?